# Are teacher salaries lower in high-need (low-income) school districts?

Tags: united-states, education

[Research Spotlight on Hard-to-Staff Schools](http://www.nea.org/tools/16917.htm)

> What characterizes "hard-to-staff" schools, those schools that have
>   difficulty in finding and retaining qualified, effective teachers?
>   Many are high-poverty inner-city schools or rural schools that, as a
>   consequence of their location in economically depressed or isolated
>   districts, offer lower salaries.

Are teacher salaries lower in low-income school districts? As in the context of this quote, are the low salaries a reason why low-income school districts are harder to staff with effective teachers? Any numbers to show this?

Comment: I added the `[united-states]` tag: the claim is US-specific.

Comment: sounds extremely fishy. More likely you'll find a difference in the number of public vs. private schools, the quality difference being caused by public schools being unable to fire underperforming teachers because of union contracts dictating tenure.

Comment: @jwenting Why is it 'fishy'? When my parents lived in a rich area of San Antonio, they told me that public education was funded from property taxes. [reference](https://www.google.com/search?q=usa+education+property+taxes)

Comment: @jwenting who or what is "fishy"? You do raise an interesting point though, that hard-to-staff and high-turnover may be just a matter of some school districts dictating tenure more than others.

Comment: @Chris public schools are funded in part from property taxes. But where their funding comes from has nothing to do with how they deal with underperforming teachers (which is generally to ignore that they're underperforming because they're protected from any disciplinary action by their union contracts).

Comment: @Michelle Three questions: a) Are you only interested in the teacher salaries, or also interested in other/all types of spending on education (textbooks, buildings, etc.)? b) Are you only interested in recent statistics, or also interested in earlier (e.g. 2004 and earlier) statistics? c) What's the intent behind your second question, which is that "If it's true that salaries are lower, is this /a/ reason why they're harder to staff?": wouldn't this be taken for granted / axiomatic in America, where salaries (financial compensation) are assumed to be /a/ motive when people choose their work?

Comment: @jwenting Please don't use this question as a vehicle for advancing your own political conspiracy theories.

Comment: It does seem simple on the face of it that low-income school districts don't have as much money, and so aren't able to pay their teachers more. Any particular reason we are skeptical of this claim?

Comment: @DJClayworth One reason (the only reason that I know of) to be skeptical is that or if there have been some (perhaps relatively recent) attempts by some State-level and/or Federal-level agencies to equalize monies across districts.

Comment: Wouldn't that be an indication that there *are* differences?

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes, of course. IMO, the things that may make this question too time-consuming to answer casually include: a) Old data (e.g. from 10+ years ago); b) Data on total spending, not specifically on teacher salaries (though, salaries are said to be the greatest part of the spending; c) Locale-specific data (e.g. from New York State, not from every State); d) Alternatively, State-wide data (not broken down by district; e) Unsorted data (not sorted by high-/low-income districts); f) Ranges of teacher salaries (which vary significantly according to teachers' experience); g) Subjective ...

Comment: ... metrics (how do you measure "harder to staff"?); h) Confounding factors (if a district has poor results then do you blame "ineffective teachers", or do you blame the parents and/or other socio-economic factors?)

Comment: @ChrisW The situation in Texas was that *local* property taxes funded each district for a long time. That changed in ... maybe it was the '80s ... funding was partially consolidated throughout the state. The money still comes from local (and locally set) property taxes, but it is collected and distributed at a state level. And it is a major matter of contention in state politics. Poking around Google suggests that is is coming up again. But that is not a national pattern, Texas has always had a need to be a little weird.

Comment: @dmckee Are you sure? The first page of [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=usa+property+tax+education+districts)) imply there's local (district-level) taxes for local spending, in multiple States other than Texas: [USA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/School_district#United_States); [VT](http://www.state.vt.us/tax/pvredtaxrates.shtml); [OH](http://www.tax.ohio.gov/school_district_income.aspx); [UT](http://www.deseretnews.com/article/700076111/Legislature-looking-into-how-to-equalize-tax-funding-between-rich-and-poor-school-districts.html?pg=all); and, presumably, others as well.

Comment: @ChrisW Well I was young when it happened in 84 (I think), and I haven't lived there in years, and there was some kind of formula that let districts keep some of what they raised out of the state-wide pool. But I'm sure that a big chunk of it went into a statewide distribution scheme. This came about as a result of a court ruling so there was much *sturm und drang* about it.

Comment: @dmckee This [rich area of San Antonio](http://www.ahisd.net/about/lawsuit.html) is an independent school district, fighting a 2012 lawsuit, saying "50%" of its income is recaptured by the State". [This article](http://www.ascd.org/publications/educational-leadership/may02/vol59/num08/Unequal-School-Funding-in-the-United-States.aspx) says that funding-per-student varies between and within States by a factor of 2 or more, and (year 2000) "Nearly half of the funding for public schools in the United States ... is provided through local taxes, generating large differences in funding between etc."

Comment: @ChrisW Yes. Funding in Texas is weird. The taxes are local, the distribution is partially state and partially local. That's what I said. Or at least what I was trying to say. BTW, back when I was going to school in San Antonio, the folks in Alamo Heights would insist that they are not part of San Antonio proper. Even thought their citylet is completely surround by the metropolis.

Comment: @dmckee http://www.ascd.org/publications/educational-leadership/may02/vol59/num08/Unequal-School-Funding-in-the-United-States.aspx seems to say, using data from the year 2000, that Texas isn't as 'weird' as you suggest: a) 50% of education/district spending is generated locally b) this happens in the United States generally (not only in Texas) c) spending-per-student varies by a factor of approximately two between States, and by a factor of up to two or more between the districts within some States.

Comment: @DJClayworth iow, "don't post things that are not in line with a far left political agenda". Duly noted, being skeptical of left wing political practices is not allowed here. I don't advance any agenda, I merely point out what agenda is being advanced in those schools as it has a profound effect on how they're being run.

Comment: @jwenting You 'merely' pointed out *your claim* that there is a left wing conspiracy. That's called advancing your own agenda.

Comment: @jwenting "*I merely point out what agenda is being advanced in those schools*" — that is not an appropriate use of comments.